# Remove vertical space between two chapters in table of contents in latex

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I want to remove vertical space between two chapters in table of contents.
I can remove the vertical space between chapter and a section by using

```
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip -2pt}
```

But i dont know how to remove the spaces between two chapters. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting `\cftbeforechapskip`? Maybe try `\setlength{cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}`. Also it would be easier to help you if you could provide an MWE next time.

Answer (score 5):

This removes the space between 2 chapters only when they are just next to each other.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newskip\old@cftbeforechapskip
\old@cftbeforechapskip\cftbeforechapskip
\let\old@l@chapter\l@chapter
\let\old@l@section\l@section
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\old@l@chapter{#1}{#2}\cftbeforechapskip3pt}% set your value here
\def\l@section#1#2{\old@l@section{#1}{#2}\cftbeforechapskip\old@cftbeforechapskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{AAA}
\section{sss}

\chapter{BBB}
\section{ttt}

\chapter{CCC}

\chapter{DDD}

\end{document}
```

If you want to remove all the vertical spaces, you simply say the following instead of the long code in preamble:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
```